How do I get rid of this error message? Warning at 10:16 The `expr0` parameter of the `operator ?:` function accepts a 'bool' argument
How do you rewrite this script such that the line beginning with "barsInDelay :=" does not trigger the following error message: "11:38:51 AM    Warning at 10:16 The expr0 parameter of the operator ?: function accepts a 'bool' argument. To avoid potential unexpected results, pass a 'bool' value or expression to this parameter."
//@version=5

contractsPerOrder = 5
strategy("Delayed Alerts", overlay=true, initial_capital = 20000, use_bar_magnifier = true, default_qty_value = contractsPerOrder)

i_delayBars = input(1, "Delay in Bars")  // How many lower timeframe bars must pass before sending alert

var int barsInDelay = 0  // Initialize the barsInDelay variable

barsInDelay := request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1", close[1]) ? barsInDelay + 1 : 0  // Count the number of bars in the delay timeframe

delayElapsed = barsInDelay >= i_delayBars // Check if the i_delayBars have elapsed since the last alert

buyCondition = close > ta.sma(close, 20) and close[1] > close[2] and close[2] > close[3]
if buyCondition and delayElapsed
    buyAlertMessage = '{"ticker": "' + syminfo.ticker + '", "action": "buy", "price": ' + str.tostring(close) + ', "quantity": ' + str.tostring(contractsPerOrder) + '}'
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, alert_message = buyAlertMessage)

if delayElapsed
    sellAlertMessage = '{"ticker": "' + syminfo.ticker + '", "action": "sell", "price": "{{close}}", "quantity": ' + str.tostring(contractsPerOrder) + '}'
    strategy.exit("Sell", profit = 5*5, loss = 10*4)

I do not know how to eliminate the warning message. I have attempted != na, this throws a new warning; != na() is incorrect. I'm stuck.

First of all, it is a warning and not an error.
You are using request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1", close[1]) in the ternary operator as if it was returning a bool.
condition ? valueWhenConditionIsTrue : valueWhenConditionIsFalse
That does not make any sense because you are getting a price value out of it.
If you really want to get rid of the error, you should cast that expression to bool.
barsInDelay := bool(request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1", close[1])) ? barsInDelay + 1 : 0  // Count the number of bars in the delay timeframe


Thank you, all I was looking for was bool(). Appreciate it.
